# Firmware For Sony Camera

Tags: sony, firmware

How can I update the firmware for my Sony H20 camera?

Has anyone upgraded firmware for sony in the past?

Comment: Isn't this in the instruction manual? If not, it'll certainly be in the documentation with any firmware update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any firmware updates listed on the [Sony support page for that model of camera](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=DSCH20B).